# find where column value varies

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select only names where the flag value varies for the same name?

```
name    flag
ben     0
harry   1
harry   1
harry   1
john    1
john    0
john    1
krishna 1
krishna 1
luke    0
steve   1
steve   0
```

Result should select john and steve

Comment: sorry, meant varies for the same name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following which will group the data by the `name` and count the distinct flag values. If the `count` is greater than 1 then they have different flags:

```
select name
from yourtable
group by name
having count(distinct flag) > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3739d/1)

If you want to expand on this and include additional columns in your table, then you could use:

```
select t1.name, t1.flag
from yourtable t1
where exists (select name
              from yourtable t2
              where t1.name = t2.name
              group by name
              having count(distinct flag) > 1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3739d/14)

This will return both the name and the flag:

```
|  NAME | FLAG |
----------------
|  john |    1 |
|  john |    0 |
|  john |    1 |
| steve |    1 |
| steve |    0 |
```

Comment: that works very well. SQL Fiddle is very good too :). Is it possible to list in result:                                                           john    1
john    0
john    1                                                        steve   1
steve   0

Comment: @SantoshPillai see my edit with a different version of the query

Comment: Thanks. works perfectly. Can you please explain how you used t1 and t2?

Comment: @SantoshPillai `t1` and `t2` are aliases for the table.  In the query with `EXISTS`, I am using those aliases so I can make sure that the name returned matches the name returned by the `WHERE`. If you remove the `t1.name = t2.name` then all rows will be returned.  See this [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3739d/16) -- you will notice that all rows are returned which is not correct. You need the link between the outer table to the subquery to return the correct result. I used the alias to identify each table. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name
FROM Table t1 
INNER JOIN Table t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t1.flag <> t2.flag
```